# How to highlight a search result row in a datatable using the unique column value in Jquery

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm having a datatable results from ajax response.The newly inserted/updated value will be found by my logic and giving `<td>Unique value in First column<td>` which is unique but, 
my aim to perform search operation in the datatable which has pagination option as well.
How to achieve search operation using this unique value and highlight this result row.? Any solutions welcomed.
This column I'm getting value 
`$("td", row).eq(0).html(item[i].projectIcode);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below uses jquery to highlight any row where the first cell's text contents matches the text in the search box. You could trigger the function once the data has been loaded and displayed onto the webpage, passing your unique search term to the `highlight()` function.

Let me know if you need anything else.

```js
// Add change event to search box
$('#search').on('input', function() {

  // Launch higlight function, passing search term
  highlight($(this).val());

});


// Highlight function, that accepts any search string
function highlight(searchText) {

  // Remove any highlight classes already attached to a row
  $("tr.highlight").removeClass("highlight");

  // Cycle through each row
  $("tr").each(function() {

    // Check if the first cell of each row matches search term
    if (searchText == $(this).children("td").first().text()) {

      // Add highlight class to row if matches
      $(this).addClass("highlight");

    }

  });

}
```

```css
td, th {
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
}

tr.highlight {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


Search ID: <input id="search">

<hr style="margin: 20px 0px;">

<table>

  <tr>
    <th>Index</th>
    <th>More content</th>
    <th>More content</th>
    <th>More content</th>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>0001</td>
    <td>Some other content</td>
    <td>Some other content</td>
    <td>Some other content</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>0002</td>
    <td>Some other content</td>
    <td>Some other content</td>
    <td>Some other content</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>0003</td>
    <td>Some other content</td>
    <td>Some other content</td>
    <td>Some other content</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Thanks! But my doubt here is I have applied pagination, is it highlight and get me to another page suppose I'm loading from first page as well?

Comment: If the search term anywhere on the page? Or can you add it as an `attribute` to the table or similar? Then you can pull it out of the page and compare on changes (i.e. trigger `highlight()` on page load.

Comment: The search term only with in the datatable. For this case whether this code snippet works fine?

Comment: It's working fine but not redirect me to correct page when the search text is in 3rd page. How to achieve this scenario can you edit your answer please for this.

Comment: Have a look at this plugin, it does exactly what you need: https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData()